# Can someone explain me what means Akka Supervision parameter "withinTimeRange"?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

I am new in Akka and I need a example using this parameter and tips when use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [Scaladoc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.0/index.html#akka.actor.AllForOneStrategy):

**withinTimeRange** *duration of the time window for maxNrOfRetries, Duration.Inf means no window*

It comes into play with the `AllForOneStrategy` that applies when an actor fails. The `withinTimeRange` parameter describes the time window within which *all the actors* should be retried (as opposed to the specific child that failed).

As for an example, see the top answer in this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651807/how-to-detect-dead-remote-client-or-server-in-akka2).

Comment: Wow! Great explanation! I though this was applicable to OneForOneStrategy too!